# Can Grails handle encoded slashes in URL?

Tags: url, grails, encoding

I've got a Grails app, and I want to put a parameter containing tire size info in the URL. Tire size info looks like: "225/60R18 104Y". The slash is not a path separator, and fortunately, Grails is smart enough to encode it to /foo/225%2F60R18+104Y. Actually calling this URL doesn't work, however. I get a blank page, no error or anything. Turning the %2F into a slash gives me an error page (expected), and leaving it out gets me to the correct controller and action, but with the wrong size info.

So what's the problem here? Why can't Grails deal with this, and is there any way to fix that?

**Update:** Looks like both Apache and probably Tomcat are the culprits here. Apache can probably be made to behave by adding `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode`, but now I have to figure out how to get Tomcat to accept this.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `**` after parameter in URL Mapping worked for me.
For example, change `'/foo/$tire'` to `'/foo/$tire**'`

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to check that some day. I can't do that right now, because I'm not working on that project anymore. But I believe configuring Apache and Tomcat worked well.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're reading tire size as `params.id`, you can use Grails codecs:

```
def tireSize = params.id.decodeURL()
```

Regards,
Deluan

Comment: That's not it. I don't even reach the controller. Grails (or Tomcat? or Apache?) silently freaks out before I get to that point.